# How can I permanently add Homebrew to my PATH?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, apple-m1

I have an M1 Mac Mini. Every time I want to use brew in a new terminal, it tells me :

`zsh: command not found: brew`

So I always do this to solve it :

`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin`

But then the next time I open a terminal, this has been forgotten. Is there a way to make it stick? I wonder why the homebrew installation doesn't do this by default? (It does warn me that it's not added to the path during installation).

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create/open the `~/.zshrc` file and add this line to it: `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I actually tried this before, but in hindsight I think my mistake then was that I was root when I tried it, so it didn't save in the correct spot.